# Implementing VFR PDF reader in app

Tags: ios, pdf, viewer, reader

I'm new to programming and am currently working on creating a app to view PDF's for a class project.

I have added the necessary framework and files for VRF reader. I already have a slide out menu that links to different web pages and an about page. On one page I have two buttons and I want each of them to open a different PDF. I am at a loss for how to make those buttons implement the action to open a file and how to differentiate between the two pdf by which button is pressed.

I know that is a big step from where I am at to where I want to be but if anyone could help thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: So far I have Added a View controller and set its class to ReaderViewController with a present modally link between my button and the View Controller. I'm assuming I need to specify in the code which Pdf I want it to open but cannot find a place to do that, I'm also assuming I need a way to link that specific view controller with the code and the imported code to my project as a whole but agian I'm lost as to how to do that.